# How to copy files into a zip file using ANT script?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I want to copy few files into an existing zip file using ANT script.

Is there any task available for that? Or do I need to unzip the zip file then copy the needed files and zip again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation of the zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html):

> The update parameter controls what happens if the ZIP file already
>   exists. When set to yes, the ZIP file is updated with the files
>   specified. (New files are added; old files are replaced with the new
>   versions.)

Answer (score 4):

If you have an existing zip file called perlscr.zip, you can add for example, a file called backup.sh in the shellscr directory using the Ant Zip task:

```
<zip destfile="perlscr.zip"
    basedir="shellscr"
   includes="backup.sh"
   update="true"/>
```